# What is the best way to get result having multiple database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I have three db class and corresponding `viewModel` :

```
public class User
{
   public string Id{get;set;}
   public string Name{get; set;}
   public string Email{get; set;}
}

public class Post
{
     [Key]
     [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
     public long Id{get; set;};
     public string Title{get; set;}
     public string Content{get; set;}
}

public class Comment
{
     [Key]
     [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
     public long Id { get; set; }
     public long PostId { get; set; }
     [ForeignKey("PostId")]
     public Post Post { get; set; }
     public string Content{get;set;}
}
```

And there have three `services` for communicating with `database`.

**I want to get five numbers of user who write maximum post(1st list) and who has maximum comments against post.**

I have another view Model for this purpose.

```
public class TopContributorViewModel
{
     public string UserName { get; set; }
     public long PostCount { get; set; }
     public long CommentCount { get; set; }

}
```

I have a controller. What will be the best way to get that result using LINQ query?

1. call userservice?
2. call postservice?
3. call commentsercice?

And of course there have corresponding Repository for communicating db.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you class names are bogus, but whatever.  The short answer is.. this is your architecture.. YOU should know the best way to get data out of it.

Comment: 5 numbers of users? what does that refer to?

Comment: just for specific solution what I need....@ Mohammed Sohail Ebrahim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user can create and has posts and comments, there should have two references of post and comment table. Like

```
public class User
{
   public string Id{get;set;}
   public string Name{get; set;}
   public string Email{get; set;}
   public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

And after this, you can easily query through linq.
In controller,

```
public class YourController : Controller
{
        private readonly IUserService _user;

        public YourController(IUserService user)
        {
              _user = user;           
        }

        public ActionResult YourMethod()
        {
            var model = _user.GetResult();
            return View(model);
        }
}
```

In service,

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
      private readonly IUserRepository _user;

      public UserService(IUserRepository  user)
      {
         _user=user;
      }

      public List<TopContributorViewModel> GetResult()
      {
         var result = _user.FindAll(u => u.Active)
                           .Include(p=>p.Posts)
                           .Include(p=>p.Comments)
                           .Select(model=>new TopContributorViewModel
                            {
                              UserName = model.Name,
                              UserId = model.Id,
                              PostCount = model.Posts.Count(u=>u.IsPublished==true && u.UserId==model.Id),
                              CommentCount = model.Comments.Count(u => u.IsPublished == true && u.UserId == model.Id)
                            });
            return result.ToList();
      }

}
```

Thank you. Keep going!!!!!